# How to get aggregated values from a collection using values from the same collection as predicate

Tags: c#

I have a list containing `Employee Model Objects`.

```
public List<EmployeeModel> EmployeeData()
{
    return new List<EmployeeModel>()
    {
         new EmployeeModel(){ EmpID = 1, EmpSSN = 11, LName = "Motor", FName = "Mouse" },
         new EmployeeModel(){ EmpID = 2, EmpSSN = 11, LName = "Motor", FName = "Mouse" },
         new EmployeeModel(){ EmpID = 3, EmpSSN = 11, LName = "Motor", FName = "Mouse" },

         new EmployeeModel(){ EmpID = 1, EmpSSN = 12, LName = "Cat", FName = "Auto" },
         new EmployeeModel(){ EmpID = 2, EmpSSN = 12, LName = "Cat", FName = "Auto" },
    };
}
```

I need to list each employee and their total EmpSSN occurrence so that the output will look like this:

```
Last Name: Mouse. Total EmpSSN: 3
Last Name: Cat. Total EmpSSN: 2
```

I can do something like this to get the names:

```
var name = data.EmployeeData().Select(x => x.LastName).Distinct();
```

However, I am not certain how to get the EmpSSN Count without writing extraneous code or using the same list twice, given I will not know the data in the list or have arguments to pass.

Comment: What is "total EmpSSN occurrence"?  Is that the same as "number of rows" ?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it will be the occurrence of rows for each employee rather then rows of entire collection.

Comment: There is no field named "employee." Can you define your requirements in terms of the actual data elements in front of you? E.g. number of rows per unique `LName`, or number or rows per unique `EmpID`. These are all different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `Distinct`, use `GroupBy`:

```
var name = data.EmployeeData()
    .GroupBy(x => x.LastName)
    .Select(g => new {
        LastName = g.Key
    ,   TotalEmpSsn = g.Count()
    });
```

Since `LastName` is used as the group's key, `Select` gets groups combining records with identical last name. If you are looking to coult items within the group where a specific predicate would be true (e.g. `EmpSsn` above a certain number, etc.) you can supply that predicate to the `Count()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I would group them first by LastName then call Sum() on the EmpSSN like so:

```
var data = EmployeeData()
   .GroupBy(e => e.LastName)
   .Select(e => new { 
      EmpID = e.Key, 
      EmpSSN = e.Select(emp => emp.EmpSSN).Sum() 
   });
```